# Procedure to compile the linux kernel for an embedded device - installing headers files in the system

Tags: linux, makefile, kernel, embedded-linux

I am compiling a linux kernel (4.9.15) in my host machine and installing it in an embedded device. All works fine but I have a question about the proper way to install all the include files in the system (/usr/include/linux with updated version.h)

This is how I proceed:

1. I compile the sources in my host machine.
2. My compilation script generates boot.tar.gz, modules-4.9.15.tar.gz, linux-4.9.15.tar.gz and linux-headers-4.9.15.tar.gz and copy them to the embedded system
3. In the embedded system I extract boot.tar.gz (containing System.map-4.9.15, config-4.9.15, initrd.img-4.9.15 and vmlinuz-4.9.15) to /boot folder, the modules-4.9.15.tar.gz to /lib/modules and the source and headers files to /usr/src/
4. I update the /lib/modules/4.9.15 "source" and "build" links to point to /usr/src/4.9.15 folder
5. In /usr/src/linux-4.9.15 folder I do `make install_headers`
6. I update grub with `update-grub2` and reboot

My doubt is how to update the system's /usr/include/linux/ folder. I thought that executing `make headers_install` would do it but it just installs the include files in the sources folder. Should I copy the generated /usr/src/linux-4.9.15/usr/include/linux folder to the system's /usr/include/linux manually? Is that the proper way to do it?
Any suggestion to do the process in a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI the typical *embedded* Linux system does not need/use headers.  And you need to learn the difference between a folder and directory.

Comment: Thank you sawdust for such an usefull answer. I agree, in production you don't usually need/use headers, but I am working in a development unit where I am doing many changes, compiling different libraries and code that is easier to test in the target device instead of in the host machine that does not have all the peripherals. 
I always thought that "folder" and "directory" was mainly the same, probably because English is not my mother tongue.. thanks for pointing that out, I will search for the difference. In the mean time you can use "directory" in my post in order to understand my question